# Delete file from Unix system

Tags: linux, unix

I want to delete a text file from Unix machine. I am using the following command for the same.

```
rm /tmp/filename.txt
```

It is working fine. After execution it returns nothing.

I want to get some conformation about deletion as follows,

```
filename.txt deleted successfuly.
```

Please any one help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following to slove my issue.

```
rm -v /tmp/filename.txt
```

this will display the message as follows,

```
removed `/tmp/filename.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands:

```
rm /tmp/filename.txt && echo "File successfuly deleted"
```

this will remove the file and then (only if the exit status of command is successful) print the message.

---

Otherwise, as Venkat said, you can use `rm -i` that asks for confirmation before deleting the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use option with Unix command please See
[this link](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_rm.htm) below

Answer (score 0):

The below command prompts you once whether you want to remove the file before deleting it.

```
rm -i tmp/filename.txt
```

If the file is unavailable shows you :

```
cannot remove ‘tmp/filename.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Hope it helps.